# スラッシュ / を含むフォルダは作れないらしいのですがどうしたらよいでしょうか？

Tags: python

ヤフーから株価をCSVで取り込むプログラム（下記）を走らせる前に「※ 実行前にcsvの保存用の”./data/stock_price_data”というフォルダを作成しておく必要があります。」と書いてあったので作ろうと思いましたがスラッシュが使えないようで同じ名前のフォルダが作れません。どの様にしたらいいでしょうか？

```
start = datetime.date(2010,1,1)
end = datetime.date.today()

for index, row in df_data_j.iterrows():
    try:
        df = web.DataReader(f'{row["コード"]}.T', 'yahoo', start, end)
    except:
        print("error")
    
    df.to_csv("./data/stocks_price_data/stock_price_data_{}.csv".format(row["コード"]))
```

Comment: 「スラッシュが使えないようで同じ名前のフォルダが作れません」と推測を述べるのではなく、具体的なエラーメッセージを掲載することをお勧めします。質問者さんの理解できなかった原因について説明が得られ、問題が解決することがあります。

Comment: 「ありがとう」というために自分の質問や回答にコメントをつけないでください。[自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) を参考に対応してください。結局この質問は解決したのですか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ”./data/stock_price_data”というフォルダ

これは `.` （現在のフォルダ）の中に `data` というフォルダを作り、その `data` というフォルダの中に `stock_price_data` というフォルダを作る、という意味です。

「フォルダの階層構造」を学んでください。

Answer (score 0):

質問には明記されていませんが、恐らく実行環境が Windows なのだろうと推測されます。

Windows ではファイル・フォルダ名に `/` スラッシュを含める事ができませんが、OS によってフォルダ (ディレクトリ) の区切り文字の表現方法が異なるだけなので、(別の回答にもある通り) 以下のような階層構造でフォルダを用意すればよいはずです。

```
┌ プログラム
└ data/
    └ stocks_price_data/
        └ stock_price_data_*.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

「/」はファイル名の一部ではなく、階層構造を表す文字です。

> ”./data/stock_price_data”

他の方の回答にあるとおり、「.」は現在いるフォルダ（を省略した表現）です。
実際は「/XXX/YYY/ZZZ」みたいになっています。
= XXXフォルダの中のYYYフォルダの中のZZZフォルダにいる。

フォルダの作り方ですが、
pythonではなく、GUI上（MacならFinder、windowsならエクスプローラー）でフォルダを作成する方法をおすすめします。

参考：
現在のフォルダ「.」はpythonコマンドを実行する場所であることがデフォルトです。
コンソール上で「pwd」と打ったら「.」が省略しない形で見えると思います。